# Newton's Raphson method - Absolute error

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Can someone explain to me how the '$e_k$' section is evaluated?
I know that the absolute error is 
$|x - x_n|$ but I can't understand how this values came up.

[image]

Comment: This looks like some kind of error relative to the value of $x$ in each iteration, since its value in the last iterations doesn't change much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is strange, especially as that presumed error does not go to zero while the iteration visibly converges. In general when the Newton iteration is in its quadratically convergent phase, the step length $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ is a good proxy for for the error $e_n=|x_n-x_*|$. Using that for a reconstruction of the table via a script

```
f=lambda x: x**3-3*x+2
df=lambda x: 3*(x**2-1)
x=0; e=1;
for k in range(20):
    x0, x = x, x-f(x)/df(x);
    e0, e = e, abs(x-x0);
    print("%3d & %.15f & %.6e & %.6e & %.6f \\\\"%(k, x0, f(x0), e, e/e0))
```

gives as output

\begin{array}{lllll}
\hline
k&x_k&f(x_k)&e_k&e_k/e_{k-1}^1\\
\hline
  0 & 0.000000000000000 & 2.000000e+00 & 6.666667e-01 & 0.666667 \\
  1 & 0.666666666666667 & 2.962963e-01 & 1.777778e-01 & 0.266667 \\
  2 & 0.844444444444444 & 6.882853e-02 & 7.996430e-02 & 0.449799 \\
  3 & 0.924408746095493 & 1.671018e-02 & 3.829050e-02 & 0.478845 \\
  4 & 0.962699246921644 & 4.122140e-03 & 1.876853e-02 & 0.490161 \\
  5 & 0.981467772499906 & 1.023966e-03 & 9.295002e-03 & 0.495244 \\
  6 & 0.990762774217152 & 2.551908e-04 & 4.625756e-03 & 0.497661 \\
  7 & 0.995388530630080 & 6.369888e-05 & 2.307511e-03 & 0.498840 \\
  8 & 0.997696041548041 & 1.591244e-05 & 1.152422e-03 & 0.499422 \\
  9 & 0.998848463636218 & 3.976581e-06 & 5.758787e-04 & 0.499712 \\
 10 & 0.999424342384743 & 9.939543e-07 & 2.878564e-04 & 0.499856 \\
 11 & 0.999712198815501 & 2.484647e-07 & 1.439075e-04 & 0.499928 \\
 12 & 0.999856106311234 & 6.211320e-08 & 7.194857e-05 & 0.499964 \\
 13 & 0.999928054881270 & 1.552793e-08 & 3.597299e-05 & 0.499982 \\
 14 & 0.999964027872790 & 3.881935e-09 & 1.798617e-05 & 0.499991 \\
 15 & 0.999982014044032 & 9.704779e-10 & 8.993004e-06 & 0.499995 \\
 16 & 0.999991007048069 & 2.426188e-10 & 4.496482e-06 & 0.499998 \\
 17 & 0.999995503530551 & 6.065481e-11 & 2.248244e-06 & 0.500001 \\
 18 & 0.999997751774110 & 1.516343e-11 & 1.124104e-06 & 0.499992 \\
 19 & 0.999998875878467 & 3.790968e-12 & 5.620640e-07 & 0.500011 \\
\hline
\end{array}

This is the typical behavior at a root of multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I was wondering what i am doing wrong but it seems that the notes in the photo are wrong.

Comment: The notes, as far as visible, are correct. The table does not contain what it apparently announces in the column titles for the last 2 columns. It is possible that an exact root as a constant in the script was used in the error computation, only it was not an exact root of this polynomial.